# Qt: Qt 6.1.1 Ошибка отображения qml. Failed to create vertex shader: Error 0x80070057

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qml, qt6

Всем привет! Я новый пользователь qt, и у меня возникла проблема с qml. Этот вопрос уже обсуждался в [этой статье](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66513315/failed-to-build-graphics-pipeline-state-in-qt-quick-application), но для python. Я же пишу на C ++ / Qt 6.1.1, QtCreator 4.15.1 для open source. Помоги мне, пожалуйста.

Суть проблемы заключается в следующем: qml не работает, в выводе приложения отображается следующее сообщение: *"Failed to create vertex shader: Error 0x80070057: ???????? ????? ???????. Failed to build graphics pipeline state "*.

В документации Qt сказано, что это из-за «Адаптации графа сцены». Вот ссылка: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtquick-visualcanvas-adaptations.html.

Я пробовал использовать этот метод из статьи в main: *QQuickWindow :: setSceneGraphBackend ("QT_QUICK_BACKEND");* Для этого также необходимо подключить библиотеку *QQuickWindow*.

Однако Qt выдает следующую ошибку: *Could not create scene graph context for backend 'QT_QUICK_BACKEND' - check that plugins are installed correctly in C: /Qt/6.1.1/mingw81_64/plugins*
И вот тут я уже не понимаю, что делать ...

Код привожу для ясности. Так как в qml достаточно создать окно и включить в него *Rectangle {}*.

Я взял код из примера (попробовал 3 примера QtQuick). Вот код main-a:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QQuickWindow::setSceneGraphBackend("QT_QUICK_BACKEND");
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/sidepanel.qml"));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

QML код:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 360
    height: 520
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Side Panel")

    //! [orientation]
    readonly property bool inPortrait: window.width < window.height
    //! [orientation]

    ToolBar {
        id: overlayHeader

        z: 1
        width: parent.width
        parent: Overlay.overlay

        Label {
            id: label
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Qt Quick Controls"
        }
    }

    Drawer {
        id: drawer

        y: overlayHeader.height
        width: window.width / 2
        height: window.height - overlayHeader.height

        modal: inPortrait
        interactive: inPortrait
        position: inPortrait ? 0 : 1
        visible: !inPortrait

        ListView {
            id: listView
            anchors.fill: parent

            headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
            header: Pane {
                id: header
                z: 2
                width: parent.width

                contentHeight: logo.height

                Image {
                    id: logo
                    width: parent.width
                    source: "images/qt-logo.png"
                    fillMode: implicitWidth > width ? Image.PreserveAspectFit : Image.Pad
                }

                MenuSeparator {
                    parent: header
                    width: parent.width
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.bottom
                    visible: !listView.atYBeginning
                }
            }

            footer: ItemDelegate {
                id: footer
                text: qsTr("Footer")
                width: parent.width

                MenuSeparator {
                    parent: footer
                    width: parent.width
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.top
                }
            }

            model: 10

            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                text: qsTr("Title %1").arg(index + 1)
                width: listView.width
            }

            ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
        }
    }

    Flickable {
        id: flickable

        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: overlayHeader.height
        anchors.leftMargin: !inPortrait ? drawer.width : undefined

        topMargin: 20
        bottomMargin: 20
        contentHeight: column.height

        Column {
            id: column
            spacing: 20
            anchors.margins: 20
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right

            Label {
                font.pixelSize: 22
                width: parent.width
                elide: Label.ElideRight
                horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                text: qsTr("Side Panel Example")
            }

            Label {
                width: parent.width
                wrapMode: Label.WordWrap
                text: qsTr("This example demonstrates how Drawer can be used as a non-closable persistent side panel.\n\n" +
                           "When the application is in portrait mode, the drawer is an interactive side panel that can " +
                           "be swiped open from the left edge. When the application is in landscape mode, the drawer " +
                           "and the content are laid out side by side.\n\nThe application is currently in %1 mode.").arg(inPortrait ? qsTr("portrait") : qsTr("landscape"))
            }
        }

        ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
    }
}
```

Что делать???

Comment: `qputenv("QT_QUICK_BACKEND", "software");` перед `app`?

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Просто я реально не шарю...

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо большое! А ты где-то нашёл инфу, или уже из собственного опыта? Просто я хочу понимать, где вообще искать инфу в случае таких ошибок...

Comment: Дык по первой ссылке из вопроса есть ответ, только в коде на питоне.

Comment: Ну, переложить код с питона на с++ я хз как. Спасибо тебе ещё раз